# What is this diagram called

Tags: categorical-data, proportion

Can anyone tell me what is the name of this type of diagram ( if any )?
Also can anyone suggest any tools, however simple, to plot such a diagram?

[image]

Comment: ok for anyone else that might see this... while the other suggestions are good in a general sense i have found a very handy piece of software exactly for this purpose... its just called treemap... it looks kinda antiquated but its really brilliant... here is the link http://www.treemap.com/

Comment: For a similar sort of display (but not quite the same thing), see *mekko* charts.

Comment: Although some people have argued that this is not a "mosaic plot," quite clearly it is, at least according to many authorities. The fact that some software might call it one thing and other software another does not make either one uniquely correct.

Comment: i also found you can do this in google sheets in google drive... i guess its pretty recent it wasnt there a while ago

Answer (score 13):

This plot called as "Tree plot" in tableau. You can see [here](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/buildexamples_treemap.html) to know how to do that. You can find trail version of Tableau [here](http://www.tableau.com/products/trial?os=windows)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 5):

If the difference between tree plot and mosaic plot coincides with the distinction between hierarchically-arranged categories and how single categories are broken down, then OP's image would appear to be a tree plot.

At first blush, I believed that the plot was a [mosaic plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_plot), which is one way to present stratified categories. A tutorial on the construction of mosaic plots in R can be found [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/mosaic.html).

I'll research this issue further when I have a moment.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article, the purpose of a mosaic plot is to show relations between two or more qualitative variables. The plot asked about by the poster rather visualizes hierarchical discrete distributions. It looks similar, and there may be cases where both coincide, but I don't believe your answer is generally correct.

Comment: I think it is more accurately called a [Treemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping)

Comment: I've downvoted, as this is not correct. This is a type of diagram called a treemap, originally created by Ben Schneiderman. Here is one R package to calculate them, [treemap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/treemap/index.html), but I imagine there are others. Mosaic plots have a hierarchy based on the abscissa of the plot, no such hierarchy exists in tree map layouts. (Mosaic plots are more like stacked bar charts, it is just the bars have varying widths.)

Comment: On the contrary, @AndyW, this answer *is* correct.  It is well-supported by many references.  Being called one thing by one reference does not make all other names wrong.

Comment: I disagree @whuber, and [here is my response](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/momkxh24fh1lm45/Treemaps_not_Mosaic.html?dl=0). I'm not quite sure where/why you think this is "well supported by many references" - care to elaborate?

Comment: @Andy: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Mosaic+plot%22&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CDYQsARqFQoTCPTxkfKnkMcCFQEZPgodyl8FUA&biw=1624&bih=956 .  Your references are great-thank you for sharing them.  The OP's graphic appears to be an example of Friendly's $n$-way mosaic plot and could be generated *directly* from an appropriate table using mosaic plotting software. Similarly, it seems any mosaic plot could be produced with a treemap application. That leaves only the matter of coloring, which seems to be deployed opportunistically to display additional variables in either case.

Comment: I already discussed that exact same google image search in my response @whuber. I do not see how you conclude `It is well-supported by many references` from it. The assertion that each are special cases of one another given the different algorithms to draw them is amazing. Here I made an example [treemap using the R](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g0x7q3k1qkgc6tj/AAASgMFfKMqX6R5QLD001Zdna?dl=0) , and the box coordinates are saved in the csv file. I await an actual example of using a mosaic layout to generate a synonymous example.

Answer (score 4):

Treemapping is an information visualization method displaying hierarchical data by using nested rectangles.

[image: mosaic plot]
[image: Mekko chart or Marimekko chart]

It has origins in mosaic plots (left) or Marimekko charts (right), adding nesting or embedding to the standard mosaic structure. The one you displayed is well-balanced, without elongated, skinny rectangles, that degrade the appearance of some treemaps generated by the ["slice-and-dice" tiling algorithm](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=545442).

So it belongs to the subspecies of "squarified treemaps", that can be decorated with colors or shading in cushion treemaps. A description is given in Mark Bruls et al. (2000) [Squarified Treemaps](https://graphics.ethz.ch/teaching/scivis_common/Literature/squarifiedTreeMaps.pdf), Proceedings of the Joint EUROGRAPHICS and IEEE TCVG Symposium on Visualization in Amsterdam, The Netherlands, May 29–30, 2000. Apparently, the idea of squarifying, i. e. constraining rectangles to low aspect ratio, was already present in M. Zizi M. and M. Beaudouin-Lafon (1994). [Accessing Hyperdocuments Through Interactive Dynamic Maps](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.7715&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Proceedings of the 1994 ACM European conference on Hypermedia technology.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a variation of [mosaic plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_plot).

[image]

(*source: [statmenthods.net](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/mosaic.html)*)

Comment: Tim, both your illustration and that in the question are clearly the same type of thing. Moreover, they both "show relations between two or more ... variables" by visualizing a certain hierarchy of conditional probabilities.  Thus I think Andy W. and A. Donda were wrong to convince user777 that his answer is incorrect. I hope you will reconsider undeleting your answer.

Comment: @whuber since it is disputable, let it be so. I do not really consider this kind of plots useful and do not use those much, so I won't argue that I am right about this, but still it seemed plausible.

Comment: Disputation in this case is easily resolved by appealing to authorities. The briefest glance at the images Google displays in response to a search for "mosaic plot" is enough to show that a very large number of people consider the OP's example to be a mosaic plot. It's not hard to find some credible authorities among them. What really is of interest is not what various people might choose to call such a plot, but how it is constructed, how one reads it, and what it is good for.  That is the kind of information I hope will eventually be included in some of the answers here.

Comment: I've posted a response to why the OP's chart [is not a mosaic plot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/momkxh24fh1lm45/Treemaps_not_Mosaic.html?dl=0). How it is constructed is the key. In the sense that both treemaps and mosaic plots represent probabilities by areas they are the same, but one is not a variation of the other. Each have different layouts that make them visually distinct, and are used in different situations.

Comment: Sorry @AndyW but it does not convince me. What in the plot that OP posted makes it more about "arbitrary sets of hierarchical information" rather then about conditional probability..? Probability "in subsets" is conditional probability. Also the of the plots is the same. Even using your definition - for me - the plot posted by OP seems to visualize conditional probability rather than "arbitrary hierarchy".

Comment: The major differences are in the layout algorithms, which myself and others have already provided references for. For the mosaic plots one is visualizing *the same* outcome among a different set of categories. In Tim's example, for one example `Probability(Brown Eyes|Brown Hair)` vs `Probability(Brown Eyes|Black Hair)`. This is why mosaic plots will make room for zero categories, because if say `Probability(Red Eyes|Black Hair) = 0`, and `Probability(Red Eyes|White Hair) = 0.01`, that is a useful comparison to make.

Comment: For treemaps typically the lowest level boxes are all unique labels (hence *arbitrary sets of hierarchical information*, although I agree that arbitrary is not the best descriptor). In the OP's example the graphic is made to be able to say the probability of the different colors, and then labelled to see the probability of different sub-categories. For example one might say from looking at the graphic, `Probability(Light Blue)` is the largest among the different colors.

Comment: One could make the comparison that `Prob(Insulated win...|Dark Blue)` vs `Prob(Transmis...|Dark Blue)`, which is conditional, but for most applications I have seen the marginal probabilities is probably of the most interest, e.g. just the `Prob(Insulated winding...)`. Shneiderman's original problem of visualizing what is taking up disk space is a good example. `Prob(Insulated win...|Dark Blue)` vs `Prob(Transmis...|Dark Blue)` does not help with how much space you will save when deleting either category. The labels in the OP's graph of the marginal proportions support this interpretation.

Comment: @AndyW sorry, I simply don't see it, for me both plots are very similar. The more I try to see the differences, the less I am able to do so. For me it is like an argument with "Quilt plots": https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2014/01/16/quilt-plots-like-heat-maps-only-heat-maps/

Comment: I share the confusion in the opposite direction, I don't see how anyone would confuse the two. I've provided references in the linked separate page on the different layout algorithms. The squarify treemap layout in particular is easy to spot, it is intentionally designed to make the aspect ratio's of the boxes close to 1. A key point for mosaic plots is that it is still meaningful to make *length* comparisons in at least one of the dimensions. This is not the case for treemaps, only area of the boxes matters for treemaps.

Comment: @AndyW with mosaic plot it is height and width of boxes, so they differ in area... Underlying algorithm is just a matter of implementation.